# jQuery - Alert when 3 iframes are loaded

Tags: jquery

I have three iframes in my website which src I don't own.

**HTML**

```
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://a.com"></iframe>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://b.com"></iframe>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://c.com"></iframe>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
     alert("Loaded");
});
```

**The problem**: Message "Loaded" is displayed thrice. I want the messaje "Loaded" to be displayed only once, just when all iframes load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a counter variable to count how many times load event is fired for iframe. You can show alert only when counter reaches 3.

```
count = 0;    
$('iframe').load(function(){
     count++;
     if(count == 3)
        alert("Loaded");
});
```

**Edit:** To alert when all the iframes in the page are loaded. We can find the total number of iframes in [doucment.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure we get all iframes.

```
count = 0;   
totalFrames = 0; 
$(function(){
    totalFrames = $('iframe').length;
});
$('iframe').load(function(){
     count++;
     if(count == totalFrames)
        alert("Loaded");
});
```

Comment: can you edit your answer with a second code that counts the number of iframes of a page and if the counted number of iframes are loaded, then displayed "Loaded". thank you again!